# How can i remove brackets from result string?

Tags: string, jsp

This is my jsp page.

```
<body>
    <%
        String a[] = {"PAK", "ENG", "IND", "USA","SA"};
        String b[] = {"ON", "UK", "IND", "ENG", "SA","USA"};  
        final List<String> listA = Arrays.asList(a);
        final List<String> listB = Arrays.asList(b); 
        final List<String> duplicatesList = new ArrayList<String>(listA);
        duplicatesList.retainAll(listB);           
        final List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(listA);
        result.addAll(listB);
        result.removeAll(duplicatesList);            
        out.println(result);
    %>
</body>
```

Here I'm getting output as `[PAK, ON, UK]`. How can I remove brackets and display result as `PAK,ON,OK` only.

Comment: Just as a by-the-way comment, it is not good practice to put Java Code scriplets inside the JSP Files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  out.println(result);
```

above stetment prints array of string so the output you are getting.

Iterate through the list and display in appropreate format :)

```
for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
  out.print(result.get(i));
  if(i!=result.size()-1){
    out.print(",");
  }

}
```

**This is uncompiled(basic understanding) code. you can modify it a bit according** requirements

Comment: I'm new to this,could you please tell me the logic

Answer (score 0):

This will split the list after ignoring the first and last ..

```
String.valueOf(result).subSequence(1, String.valueOf(result).length()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

result is an ArrayList object which stores values in a array of objects. So basically you are storing values in a array and try to print that array using

```
out.println()
```

Printing array directly will attract a brace appended in both ends, marking them as array. So, if you don't want to have braces printed iterate through the array as described above.

Thanks